# c++ iterate over multidimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Here is an example of iterating over multidimensional array. It works as I checked (compiled using g++ 4.8.1). My question is: why does it work? Why element following the last element of array is a pointer to NULL pointer?

```
struct Test {
    int i;
};

Test** tab = new Test*[12];
for (int i=0; i<12; ++i) {
    tab[i] = new Test();
    tab[i]->i = i;
}
while (*tab != NULL) {
    std::cout<<(*tab)->i<< std::endl;
    ++tab;
}
```

Comment: Because you got lucky?

Comment: Where is the multidimensional array?

Comment: I see a one dimensional array of pointers to `Test`.

Comment: If this isn't homework, you should probably consider using `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Collin: You're right. It's array of pointers, two stars, that's why I call it multidimensional. Forget that wrong name. The core question is: why does it work? I've checked few examples and every behaves the same, I think it is not matter of luck.

Comment: Since we've clarified that there is no multidimensional array, I agree that it it just so happens that the value in memory after the 11th index of "tab" is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the side effect of the compiler trying to align the stack to a particular multiple of bytes boundary. When it does this, you will see zero-padding after a buffer.

Consider the program below, where I have tried to capture the essence of the question without as much extraneous looping.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define SIZE 12
struct Test {
    int i;
};

int main(){
    Test** tab = new Test*[SIZE];
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; ++i) {
        tab[i] = new Test();
        tab[i]->i = i;
    }
    printf("%p\n", *(tab + SIZE));
}
```

If you change `#define 12` to `#define 13` on my system, the output will no longer be `nil`.

This implies that it *does not deterministically work*, and you did indeed **get lucky**.